# typo3 tsconfig url parameters media

Tags: youtube, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x, tsconfig

We are using Typo3 7.6.

We use a simple `text and media` Element to embed youtube videos.
Those youtube video-embed links do need paramters (like rel=0), but I see no option to imput them and I do not find any typoScript where I can set those parameters in any help. Putting the paramters directly into the URL that I enter in the element does not work, merely the ID is parsed.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set buttons.link.queryParametersSelector.enabled to true in your page TS-Config.
To do this edit your rootpage(normally id=1) and go to tab Resources.
Fill in the following code to the field Page TSConfig.

```
RTE.default.buttons.link.queryParametersSelector.enabled = 1
```

After saving you should see an additional field called "Additional link parameters" when you use the link wizard.

[Reference: EXT: rtehtmlarea -> buttons.link.queryParametersSelector.enabled](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/rtehtmlarea/Configuration/PageTsconfig/interfaceConfiguration/Index.html#buttons-link-queryparametersselector-enabled)

Comment: What does the RTE buttons have todo with the GalleryProcessor??

Comment: Please provide a proper answer and help instead of criticize other answers

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use fluid styled content? If so, the gallery processer could be configured via TypoScript setup like this:

```
lib.contentElement.settings {
  media {
    additionalConfig {
        no-cookie = 1
        modestbranding = 1
        relatedVideos = 0
        showinfo = 0
    }
  }
}
```